# How to override <select> key when selecting options so that i can use tab to select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, select

I am using [ng-zorro-select](https://ng.ant.design/components/select/en) using angular. This is a library but it's based on standard html and css.

Suppose i have this page:
[table with select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftWFn.png)

**This is what is happening:**

- When i press `TAB` the focus goes to the first select
- then i can type in my search option
- to select the option i have to press `ENTER` on my keyboard
- to move to the next select i have to press `TAB`

**This is what i want:**

- Pressing tab goes to the first select (or another one in the row, but i can't get `tabindex` to work for me).
- I type in my search
- Now instead of pressing `ENTER` i would like to press `TAB` to select my option
- Pressing `TAB` again will move the focus to the next element

---

My understanding here is that it has something to do with the presets that ng zorro team decided on the select option. But since it's a standard select i can't figure out how to override that specific property.

Using a simple html `<select>` works great so it is doable, i just don't know how and what i have to override to make it work.

**External Resources:**

If you want to play around you can use this Stackblitz [ng-zorro-select](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xc6m5k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) or visit the ng zorro [select](https://ng.ant.design/components/select/en) page.

I honestly know nothing about the tab key and how to handle onFocus events in angular, or how to give a specific element focus on angular.
Anyway if you do, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code of the component](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/select/select.component.ts#L448) they're calling a method to close it on `TAB` press.

If you want to keep using this component you could do a wrapper component that passes down everything but overrides the method onKeyDown to match your expected behavior.

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: I've created a [stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xc6m5k-zs5xec?file=src/app/wrapper/wrapper.component.ts) unfortunately I can't get it to work because it fails to install some dependency for a reason I ignore but I added a wrapper component which outlines how you can create a wrapper and override a method from the component